# using push_back on objects ,c++

Tags: c++, vector

I don't understand something about push_back.
 
When I use push_back on an object , does it copy all its elements using the object's 
copy constructor? (what if the object doesn't have copy constructor?)

another question:

```
vector<Course*> cs;
Course* c = new CScourse(); //CScourse inherits Course
cs.push_back(c);
```

if I use

```
delete c;
```

would it delete what I just pushed into the vector?

Comment: Yes it will. And when you try to access that pointer, you can guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes every objects are copied in a `vector`. If the `vector` has to grow, each element will be copied to the new location.  In your case, you are storing pointers to `Course` so only the pointers get copied, the actual objects remain the same.

If you `delete c;`, it will indeed delete the object pointed to by `c` that you pushed in your `vector`. The `vector` will still contain a pointer to the object that was `c` though, this is considered a dangling pointer. You would usually remove it from your `vector` before deleting it.

Comment: I think it's confusing to say that `delete c` will delete the object that was pushed into the `vector`. The `Course` object was never pushed into the `vector` - the only thing in there is the pointer.

Comment: `delete c` will delete the object (`Course`) pointed to by `c`. `c` was pushed into the `vector`, I don't understand your comment about the `Course` being pushed in the vector... it's a `vector<Course*>`, it cannot hold the `Course` itself.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. You say "it will indeed delete the object that you pushed in your `vector`."

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for pointing that out, reworded the answer a bit